# Why is $\operatorname{Int}(A) \cup \operatorname{Int}(B) \neq \operatorname{Int}(A \cup B)$?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I know that $\operatorname{Int}(A) \cup \operatorname{Int}(B) \subset \operatorname{Int}(A \cup B)$, but that the other direction does not hold, so can anybody please tell me whats wrong with the following proof?

Suppose $x \in \operatorname{Int}(A \cup B) \Rightarrow \exists \epsilon > 0 : K(x, \epsilon) \subset A \cup B$. Assume without loss of generatlity that $K(x,\epsilon) \subset A-B \Rightarrow x \in \operatorname{Int}(A) \Rightarrow x \in \operatorname{Int}(A) \cup \operatorname{Int}(B)$.

Comment: How can you "assume without loss of generality" that $K(x,\epsilon) \subset A - B$ (I'm assuming $K(x, \epsilon)$ means a ball of radius $\epsilon$ or something similar)?

Comment: I'm not sure whether you can acutally do that, but I thought that there would basically be three cases either: $K(x,\epsilon) \subset A-B, K(x,\epsilon) \subset B-A, K(x,\epsilon) \subset A \cap B.$ All of which would result in the same conclusion.

Comment: This is not the case, as many answers are pointing out. For instance, if $A = [0,1]$ and $B = [1,2]$, then $K = (1-\epsilon, 1+\epsilon)$ is contained in $A \cup B$ but does not fit in any of these three cases.

Comment: @eager2learn Consider a different case, but that should shed light: $A=\{0,1,2\}$, $B=\{2,3,4\}$. Then $C=\{1,3\}$ is a subset of $A\cup B$, but $C$ is not contained in any of $A\setminus B$, $B\setminus A$ or $A\cap B$. It holds for *elements* that if $x\in A\cup B$ than one of the following is true: $x\in A\setminus B$, $x\in B\setminus A$ or $x\in A\cap B$.

Comment: You have also $A\cup B\subseteq A\cup B$. Is it correct to conclude that $A\cup B\subseteq A-B\vee A\cup B\subseteq A\cap B\vee A\cup B\subseteq B-A$? I don't think so.

Comment: Ok thanks I assumed that this was true for subsets as well. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because it's false, in general, that $\operatorname{Int}(A\cup B)\subseteq \operatorname{Int}(A)\cup \operatorname{Int}(B)$: take $A=(0,1]$ and $B=[1,2)$. Then $\operatorname{Int}(A)=(0,1)$, $\operatorname{Int}(B)=(1,2)$, but $\operatorname{Int}(A\cup B)=(0,2)$.

You can surely assume without loss of generality that $x\in A$, but not that the neighborhood $K(x,\epsilon)$ is contained is $A$. Try picturing what happens in the above example: $K(1,\epsilon)$ contains elements that are greater than $1$ (and belong to $B$) as well as elements that are less than $1$ (and belong to $A$). Since $A\cap B=\{1\}$, no neighborhood of $1$ can be contained either in $A$ or in $B$.

---

Consider a different case, but that should shed light over your difficulty: $X=\{0,1,2\}$, $Y=\{2,3,4\}$. Then $Z=\{1,3\}$ is a subset of $X\cup Y$, but $Z$ is not contained in any of $X\setminus Y$, $Y\setminus X$ or $X\cap Y$. It holds for *elements* that if $x\in X\cup Y$ than one of the following is true: $x\in X\setminus Y$, $x\in Y\setminus X$ or $x\in X\cap Y$.

Answer (score 3):

If $X\subseteq A\cup B$, it need not be the case that $X\subseteq A$ or $X\subseteq B$.

As for a specific case, in the real numbers both the rationals and their complement have empty interior. What is the interior of the union?

Comment: Is there anything I can do to improve this answer?

Comment: No thanks, I liked your answer, but egreg has updated his answer and I thought it was more helpful. Hope you dont mind that I accepted his now.

Comment: The comment wasn't aimed at you for unaccepting, it was aimed at whoever downvoted. As far as unaccepting goes, egreg wrote an excellent answer that's worth accepting. So that's fine.

Answer (score 2):

$K(x,\epsilon) \subset A \cup B$ does not implies $K(x,\epsilon) \subset A \Delta B$. It is not true when $K(x,\epsilon) \cap (A \cap B) \neq \phi$. For example, consider $A = (0,2)$ and $B = (1,3)$ and $x = 1.5$ and $\epsilon = 0.25$.

Answer (score 2):

You assume without loss of generality that any point $x$ that lies in $A \cup B$ necessarily lies strictly in $A$ or strictly in $B$. If your point lies in the intersection $A \cap B$ your proof doesn't work. You have however proven the case where $A$ and $B$ are disjoint.

An extension of your proof by saying that the ball $K(x, \varepsilon)$ lies entirely in the intersection will not work. Look for instance at the following example: Suppose we endow $\mathbb{R}$ with the Euclidean topology, then we can look at the intervals $[0,1]$ and $[1,2]$. it is clear that $$1 \in Int([0,2])$$ But we have $$ 1 \notin Int([0,1]) \qquad 1 \notin Int([1,2]) $$
Thus providing a counterexample.

Answer (score 1):

$\operatorname{Int}([1,2]) \cup \operatorname{Int}([2,3]) =(1,2) \cup (2,3)$

$\operatorname{Int}([1,2] \cup [2,3]) = (1,3)$

$K(2, 1/10) \in \operatorname{Int}([1,2] \cup [2,3])$

There is no $\epsilon$ such that $K(2, \epsilon) \in [1,2]$ and $K(2, \epsilon) \in [2,3]$