# Counterexample to show that the interior of union may be larger than the union of interiors

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, examples-counterexamples

I know the identity $\operatorname{int}(C \cup D) \supset \operatorname{int}(C) \cup \operatorname{int}(D) $.

I need to find a counterexample showing that equality does not hold in general.

Could you please give me any hint?

Comment: Take a nice set, like a square, and chop it in half. What are the interior points of each half? (I.e., what's missing?)

Comment: See, for example: [Why is $\operatorname{Int}(A) \cup \operatorname{Int}(B) \neq \operatorname{Int}(A \cup B)$?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1303931/why-is-operatornameinta-cup-operatornameintb-neq-operatornameint). This was among the first results when searching for [interior "\cup" example site:math.stackexchange.com](https://www.google.com/search?q=interior+"\cup"+example+site:math.stackexchange.com) in google. If you search a bit, maybe you will find other related posts.

Comment: I have added ([tag:general-topology]) tag, since the notion of interior makes sense in any topological space. (Not only in metric space.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the subsets $(0,1]$ and $(1,3)$ of real line.

Comment: I cannot find a way to prove that these two intervals form a counterexample ! could you please help me?

Comment: @user189013 just compute both sides of the statement. Which point is missing in the right hand side?

Comment: I think 1 is missing?